# How does marco offsetof work when set flag __randomize_layout?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

This is a doubt when I studying kernel source codes.
I know that if a `compiler_offsetof` is defined, the marco will call `__compiler_offsetof`, otherwise it will run `((size_t)&((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)`.
But when I enable `_randomize_layout` flag to a struct, the compiler will shuffle the items inside the struct. So how does the marco work in this condition?
One of my understanding is that compiler will solve it internally if `compiler_offsetof` was defined. But I have no idea when `compiler_offsetof` is not defined.

Comment: It works exactly the same as without the flag. Take the address of the member, take the address of the struct, subtract. Or, equivalently, take the address of the member when the struct is at address 0, interpret as an integer (no need to subtract zero). Which of these actions do you suspect to go wrong?

Comment: A single randomization seed is used for the entire compilation of the kernel. Since the seed is common, each invocation of gcc can deterministically obtain the same "randomly" ordered struct. If the seed was compromised/exposed, struct randomization would be less useful (but not useless).